# dcast with condition in r

Tags: r, reshape2, dcast

```
> log_df[1:10, ]
      tagid            happened status
1  03B2ACE7 2016-06-28 18:07:36   open
2  03B2ACE7 2016-06-28 18:36:15 closed
3  03B2ACE7 2016-06-29 07:29:59   open
4  03B2ACE7 2016-06-29 08:06:23 closed
5  03B2ACE7 2016-06-30 16:10:48   open
6  03B2ACE7 2016-06-30 17:23:55   open
7  03B2ACE7 2016-07-01 10:12:06 closed
8  03B2ACE7 2016-07-01 13:39:58 closed
9  03B2ACE7 2016-07-02 10:08:40   open
10 03B2ACE7 2016-07-02 13:33:01 closed
...
```

Above is my data.
What I'd like to produce is:

```
      tagid                open               closed
1  03B2ACE7 2016-06-28 18:07:36  2016-06-28 18:36:15
2  03B2ACE7 2016-06-29 07:29:59  2016-06-29 08:06:23
3  03B2ACE7 2016-06-30 16:10:48  2016-07-01 10:12:06
...
```

I was trying to make it work with dcast in reshape2 package.
However, I have to be selective where I only pick up

"open" that is very first one and only those that comes right after closed and "close" that comes right before open.

So from log_df, row 6 and 7 will be ignored..

I am really stuck and not sure how I can go about this..
Maybe dcast is not the best approach?

Please help! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr` (from tidiverse, evolution of reshape):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
    filter((status == 'open' & lag(status, default = "") != 'open') | (status == 'closed' & lead(status, default = "") != "closed")) %>% 
    mutate(r = ceiling(row_number() / 2)) %>% 
    spread(status, happened)

#>      tagid r              closed                open
#> 1 03B2ACE7 1 2016-06-28 18:36:15 2016-06-28 18:07:36
#> 2 03B2ACE7 2 2016-06-29 08:06:23 2016-06-29 07:29:59
#> 3 03B2ACE7 3 2016-07-01 13:39:58 2016-06-30 16:10:48
#> 4 03B2ACE7 4 2016-07-02 13:33:01 2016-07-02 10:08:40
```

It:

1. Filter the data.frame with the specific condition
2. Add a column to store the 'group'
3. Spread the values to the columns (equivalent to dcast)

#### Data:

```r
df <- read.table(text = '      tagid            happened status
1  03B2ACE7 "2016-06-28 18:07:36"   open
2  03B2ACE7 "2016-06-28 18:36:15" closed
3  03B2ACE7 "2016-06-29 07:29:59"   open
4  03B2ACE7 "2016-06-29 08:06:23" closed
5  03B2ACE7 "2016-06-30 16:10:48"   open
6  03B2ACE7 "2016-06-30 17:23:55"   open
7  03B2ACE7 "2016-07-01 10:12:06" closed
8  03B2ACE7 "2016-07-01 13:39:58" closed
9  03B2ACE7 "2016-07-02 10:08:40"   open
10 03B2ACE7 "2016-07-02 13:33:01" closed', h = T)
```

Comment: In order to keep the first opens and the last closeds, thereby filtering out rows 6 and 7 from the original df, you could do instead `filter((status == 'open' & lag(status,default="") != 'open') | (status == 'closed' & lead(status,default="")!="closed"))`.

Comment: The solution above is a very good solution. It keeps the last open before a closed in case there are several opens in a row and the last closed before an open if there are several closed in a row, and then it does the `spread`. If, as in your example (ignore rows 6&7), you want to keep instead the first open and the last closed, you can replace the `filter` in the solution above by this other `filter`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I see what you mean, I didn't pay attention to which 'subsequent event' got filtered. Fixing the code with @Lamia's filter, which is good.